# Why doesn't the Weierstrass function have a derivative when its input is an integer?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The Weirstrass function is defined as $f(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} [a^n\cos(b^n\pi x)]$ for $0<a<1$, positive integer $b$, and $ab>1+\dfrac 32 \pi$. Its derivative, by the chain rule and the sum rule, should be $f'(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty [-a^nb^n\pi\sin(b^n\pi x)]$. For $n\in\mathbb Z$, $f'(n)=0$. But the function is said to be "nowhere differentiable." What is the flaw in the reasoning?

Comment: The derivate of an infinite sum is not necessarily equals with the sum of the derivates.

Answer (score 1):

The "sum rule" does not extend to infinite sums in all cases.  You need some additional hypotheses which you can find in real analysis texts.  In any case, you should be suspicious of your result because the individual terms of the sum are clearly everywhere differentiable, yet you're claiming that the sum is only differentiable at integers.  If the sum rule really worked, the sum should be differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, infinite sums can't be differentiated term by term.